# Using mvvmcross, how can I "share" a viewmodel to work with a view for iphone and another for ipad? Any special name convention?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm developing a cross platform application that targets both android and iOS (iPhone and iPad).

I'm using MvvmCross (thanks Stuart) and Xamarin.

My doubt is related to the iOS development. The application target devices is set to Universal.

I've created a view model named LoginViewModel (inside the core ViewModels directory) and a view named LoginView (inside the Views directory of the UI), so, it respects the mvvmcross naming conventions and everything works fine.

Since the primary purpose of the application is to be used on a iPad, the LoginView is an iPad ViewModelController.

But in the future, I'll be building xib for both iPad and iPhone.

To test this, I created a set of new ViewModelController (changed to extend MvxViewController) and named them LoginViewModel~ipad (ipad view controller) and LoginViewModel~iphone (iphone view controller).

Xamarin Studio didn't let me save the save with the ~ and renamed the set of files to LoginViewModel_ipad and LoginViewModel_iphone (set of files: .xib, .cs and designer.cs).

I add a set of random controls into the xib file using xCode IB and saved them.

I started the application in the iPhone simulator, but my view doesn't appear, only an empty screen (or almost empty).

[image: empty screen screen shot]

Can the same viewmodel be shared between an iPhone and iPad view?
If yes, what is the name convention for these cases?
Could you please lead me into the right direction?

Thanks for all the replies,

Luis Pinho

Answer (score 0):

Stuart covers Universal apps in the N+1 series [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=PpeysFIINcY&t=174s) . This might help.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112214/mvvmcross-mvxformfactorspecific-ipad-iphone-attributes

Comment: @Rob:thanks for the reply, I'm still in n=13. Making a custom presenter is way different from what I was going to do. Just to clarify one of the problems I had, it seems that I can use an iPhone view in both iPhone and iPad (it resizes to iPad) but the other way around is not true (view not appearing in iPhone simulator prob).

Comment: @Stuart: Thanks for the reply, in the example shown in your n=24 video you override the CreatePresenter (for an iPad device), but in the stack overflow post the MvxFormFactorSpecific attribute is used, what is the correct way if the app is for ios and droid?Any MvxFormFactorSpecific example?

Comment: The correct way is the way that makes your app do what you want it to do. Both using the presenter or using an attribute work, and both are just C# code - so you can implement what you want to.